# Как правильно чистить QHash

Tags: c++, qt, хеширование

Valgrind ругается на утечку после того как я чищу хэш, как правильно его чистить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
QHash<uint, QString>* SomeClass::GetDictionary()
{
  QHash<uint, QString>* _ret_data = new QHash<uint, QString>();
  if(someError) return nullptr;
  for(int _index = 0; _index < 4; _index++)
  {
       _ret_data->insert(i,"SOMETEXT");
  } 
  return _ret_data
}

SomeClass *myClass = new SomeClass();

QHash<uint, QString> *_h_buf = myClass->GetDictionary();
m_dict = *_h_buf;//сохраняю значения в член класса
_h_buf->clear();
delete _h_buf();
```

Comment: возможно проблема в самом QHash.

Comment: вполне вероятно, идеологически я все делаю верно?

Comment: myClass - не забываете удалять?

Comment: Удаляю, m_dict  тоже чищу.

Comment: @alexmaqess17 я много раз встречал подобное в glib/gtk и потом выясняется, что есть специальные suppress файлы, где все известные косяки описаны. И тогда valgrind их не показывает

Comment: Можете посоветовать в каком направлении двигаться? Или если это не критично и не приводит к большим утечкам, оставить как есть?

Comment: Хотя, озу ест прилично...

Comment: Вероятно, что утекает объект QHash целиком. Возможно, не в этой функции. смотрите остальные утечеки памяти.

Comment: выглядит так, что ты сам `QHash` не удаляешь... если `someError==true`, то ты точно выделенную память теряешь... зачем ты его вообще по указателю возвращаешь? (если что, Qt'шные контейнеры неявно разделяют свои данные, так что возврат их по зачению — нормальная практика)